# What questions should be in our meta FAQ?

Tags: discussion

The tag [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) is useful on many sites on this network for creating a list of questions that many users need to know but could never fit in the site FAQ. Arqade is not using that tag to its fullest potential. The tag currently has exactly 8 questions, and all are over a year old. This is not good because anyone trying to find out how our site works by looking at [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) will get a year-old picture of the site.

As such, I think we should revisit the tag. What questions should be tagged [faq](/questions/tagged/faq), and why?

Answer (score 5):

I came up with the idea of putting together a "meta policy" CW question at one point, and compiled this list of things that could potentially fit into it.  This is out of date and incomplete, (by a couple of months) but maybe it's a start?

Three tags seemed to jump out at me:

[allowed-questions](/questions/tagged/allowed-questions) [closing](/questions/tagged/closing) [site-policies](/questions/tagged/site-policies)

I tried to categorize things by whether the consensus was "allow" or "don't allow" - but there's kind of a (admittedly minor) problem that we have to update this list when we change our minds, and this might be construed as consensus when maybe there isn't any?  (ie, who decides when something's settled?)

---

Things we seem to have disallowed:

Uncategorized off-topic:

- [Game retailer policies](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4037/are-questions-about-game-companies-policies-on-topic) (off-topic)
- [Can my computer run X?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3411/can-i-ask-if-a-specific-game-will-run-on-a-specific-computer-system) (too localized)
- [What happened in patch X?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2337/are-questions-about-patch-notes-too-localized) (too localized)
- [History of game mechanics](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2694/how-do-we-feel-towards-specific-questions-about-the-history-of-a-certain-game-me) (not a practical topic about problems you face)

Subcategories of game development:

- [Programs more closely related to game development than game playing (ie, map editors)](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/544/do-map-editor-questions-belong-here)

Subcategories of recommendations:

- [Seed recommendations](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4134/what-to-do-about-seed-questions)
- [Website recommendations](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2453/list-of-blogs)
- [Computer builds](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3335/would-a-computer-build-tag-be-off-topic)

Subcategories of speculation:

- [Questions prior to release](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4111/how-should-we-handle-non-beta-pre-release-questions)
- [Rumor debunking](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3771/rumor-debunking-questions)
- [Game canon/plot questions that aren't explained in the source material](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2291/game-canon-questions-which-extend-beyond-the-context-of-the-story-and-its-materi)
- [Why did developer X do Y?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2429/why-did-they-design-it-that-way-anyway-and-why-do-we-allow-or-disallow-thes)

Subcategories of EULA/TOS/Legal issues:

- [Multiplayer cheats](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/489/how-do-we-stand-on-cheats-in-particularly-for-multiplayer-games)
- [Legality of X](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3818/whats-the-deal-with-legal)

---

Provisionally allowed, if properly scoped:

- [Memes related to gaming](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4009/could-someone-explain-this-joke-to-me) (not a practical topic about problems you face)
- [Game differences](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2853/whats-the-difference-between-fortresscraft-and-minecraft-who-cares)
- [Where to buy game X](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2707/do-we-allow-questions-about-where-to-buy-things)
- [Game company policies](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4037/are-questions-about-game-companies-policies-on-topic)
- [Comparing game elements/strategy across games](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4298/questions-about-characters-across-similar-games)
- [Pronunciation](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3214/are-pronunciation-questions-out-of-scope)
- [Abandonware](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266/should-we-allow-links-to-abandonware-game-sites)
- [Game utilities](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4145/can-we-talk-about-software-for-games)
- [Non gaming console use](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96/non-gaming-gaming-console-questions-allowed)
- [Technical support](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3576/which-type-of-technical-support-questions-are-on-topic)
- [Is X possible in game Y?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3198/can-i-do-x-questions)

Gray areas

- Easy questions [should be closed](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1882/is-it-really-acceptable-to-ask-questions-that-are-already-easily-googled) [but maybe not](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/559/whats-the-policy-regarding-easy-questions) (although enforced policy seems to be "eh")
- Website-rec [is fine](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1811/where-do-website-questions-fit-in-our-scope) unless they're [lists](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2453/list-of-blogs) (although enforced policy seems to be *-rec, KILL WITH FIRE)

Comment: "who decides when something's settled?" This is why I think that somewhere (not necessarily in [meta-tag:faq]) we need a list of currently enforced policies, with the assumption that even though it will require significant upkeep at first, it will be worth it and will eventually mostly settle down.

Answer (score 4):

I voiced my cynicism about this project in chat, but putting that aside, I think any list like this needs to include links to the following blog posts:

- [Stack Overflow: Where We Hate Fun](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/)
- [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)
- [Real Questions Have Answers](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/)
- [Q&A is Hard, Let’s Go Shopping!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)
- [Gorilla vs. Shark](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/)

Those give, more than any of the other blog posts and discussions we have here, succinctly define and explain the scope of Stack Exchange and its mission, and should be required reading for anyone who wants to delve into how the site comes to decisions about what is and isn't on-topic.

Comment: [The Trouble with Popularity](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/01/the-trouble-with-popularity/) is another good one for that.

Answer (score 4):

These have been asked after Agent posted his answer and are fitting for [faq](/questions/tagged/faq):

- [What list questions are good?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7558/what-list-questions-are-good)
- [Are trivial questions allowed on the site?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7570/are-trivial-questions-allowed-on-the-site)
- [Should a question be modified to include multiple subjects?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7580/should-a-question-be-modified-to-include-multiple-subjects)
- [When is non-game-specific still on-topic?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7608/when-is-non-game-specific-still-on-topic)
- [Is programming, in a game, on topic here?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7661/is-programming-in-a-game-on-topic-here)
- [Are duplicate questions allowed to co-exist if none of them have any upvoted or accepted answers?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7347/are-duplicate-questions-allowed-to-co-exist-if-none-of-them-have-any-upvoted-or)
- [What is an audiovisual artifact?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7383/what-is-an-audiovisual-artifact)
- [Using code ticks for technical term highlighting considered harmful](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7437/using-code-ticks-for-technical-term-highlighting-considered-harmful)
- [What does a game tag wiki excerpt need to explain?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7509/what-does-a-game-tag-wiki-excerpt-need-to-explain)
- [When does a question "support piracy and pirated games"?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7546/when-does-a-question-support-piracy-and-pirated-games)
- [Are duplicate questions a bad thing?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5299/are-duplicate-questions-a-bad-thing)
- [Please, please, please, don't edit out spam links](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5432/please-please-please-dont-edit-out-spam-links)
- [A Close Vote is not a Super-Downvote. Please don't use it as one](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5498/a-close-vote-is-not-a-super-downvote-please-dont-use-it-as-one)
- [Can I make questions about lore in Arqade?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5522/can-i-make-questions-about-lore-in-arqade)
- [When is a game publicly available?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5539/when-is-a-game-publicly-available)
- [What do we do with questions about games that can no longer be played?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5565/what-do-we-do-with-questions-about-games-that-can-no-longer-be-played)
- [Is it bad practice to upvote to help out?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5648/is-it-bad-practice-to-upvote-to-help-out)
- [Should I approve suggested edits that I don't know if they are true?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6786/should-i-approve-suggested-edits-that-i-dont-know-if-they-are-true)
- [Should we reopen questions being closed for 'unreleased game' after the game is released?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6971/should-we-reopen-question-being-closed-for-unreleased-game-after-the-game-is-r)
- [Am I using the 'very low quality' flag wrongly if the reason is because the answer is an exact duplicate of a previous one?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7038/am-i-using-the-very-low-quality-flag-wrongly-if-the-reason-is-because-the-answ)
- [What's bad in helping a person who bought legal version of a game move their save files from cracked copy?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7203/whats-bad-in-helping-a-person-who-bought-legal-version-of-a-game-move-their-sav)
- [Please don't misuse the voting system](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7240/please-dont-misuse-the-voting-system)
- [Is there a question limit?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7245/is-there-a-question-limit)

Comment: I wouldn't include the code ticks question.  It's not something that we really need to point new users to.  Experienced users should just edit, and if questioned on it, should be able to explain without pointing to the meta.

Comment: I think we should include the code ticks question, as it's an important piece of info that someone will need to know to make their use of the site the best it can be

Comment: Also, @3ventic please don't edit your answer while things are still being discussed and debated - **you** think the code ticks should stay there, and this is your answer - leave it in :)

Comment: @shanodin I took the list from my favorites and had not reviewed the list (most of my favorites are those that I consider useful for newcomers)

Comment: @shanodin the point of the FAQ tag is so that we can quickly point new users to an authoritative short list of site policies when they do something egregiously wrong.  Code ticks, like most other formatting errors, are not egregious.

Comment: @MBraedley as per [this meta question](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7759/update-the-faq-tag-or-create-a-new-tag) the FAQ tag ought to be used on all questions about site policy and decisions, as an easy way to collate the choices made by the community.

Comment: @shanodin: from that very link: "You should add the faq tag to any posts you think are essential reading or that you frequently reference in explaining policies to new users." The code ticks meta post does not meet those criteria.  It is not essential reading, and we should not need to frequently reference it.  We definitely should **not** be putting the tag on **all** questions about site policy.  Doing that would defeat the purpose, as it would make it too hard to find the relevant post when the time comes.

Answer (score 4):

In addition, this is one of my favourite questions to quote:

[Let's be nice to each other](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7624/lets-be-nice-to-each-other)

I also think this is important, since many users are still not complying with this basic accessibility consideration:

[Please fill in the alt text for images on this site](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7470/please-fill-in-the-alt-text-for-images-on-this-site)

Answer (score 4):

Here are some meta [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) posts about questions I regularly see get close votes as off-topic, despite community consensus to the contrary. It would help inform or remind users of site policy if they are tagged with [faq](/questions/tagged/faq):

#### Mod recommendations AKA "mod rec"

- ##### [Is "mod rec" really an umbrella category that we want to use? Or is it confusing the situation?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6828/4797)

As of 2023, I still see questions where mods are mentioned as possible or preferable solutions by the OP being voted to be closed as “mod recommendation”, despite the community consensus in at least two meta discussions to leave them open. Another relevant meta post: [Closed 'mod recommendation' Skyrim question - Can this question be improved and then reopened?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5547/4797)

#### Console modding/hacking, and homebrewed consoles or games

- ##### [What's the official stance on hacked/modded consoles?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/258/4797)
- ##### [How should we deal with direct questions on hardware modding?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3877/4797)

#### Games in a legal gray area, such as fan-made ROM patches

- ##### [What's our procedure for asking about not-quite-legal games?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4498/4797)

#### Lore, plot/story explanation, and the like

- ##### [Should lore questions as an entire category be banned?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7696/4797)

Other relevant meta posts on the on-topicness of lore questions:

- [When is it appropriate to close a lore question as "not addressed directly through in-universe sources"?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7673/4797)
- [Is "This question requires developer only knowledge" the same thing as developer intent?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9901/4797)
- [Do we close plot-explanation questions if the answer is 'there is no explanation'?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8473/4797)
- [Can I make questions about lore in Arqade?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5522/4797)
- [Is asking about the plot of a game accepted here?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15722/4797)
- [Game canon questions which extend beyond the context of the story and its material](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2291/4797)