# Where does this question fail?

Tags: discussion

[Where does Breath of the Wild take place in the Zelda Timeline](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/302750/where-does-breath-of-the-wild-take-place-in-the-zelda-timeline)

I really don't get where this question fails, but I'm taking in downvotes since I posted it.

I posted it before release, and then I understand I might have jumped the gun. Nobody could have the answer I was looking for because the game and it's lore wasn't out, and that made that there was no way to know officially the answer.

But now, the game is out, some dedicated people probably have already ended it, so there might be some clues on where does it take place.

But still I'm being destroyed in down votes.

Where does this go wrong?

Comment: I suppose it could be possible that people are downvoting because they see it as an off-topic question (dev intention). Another possibility is that the downvoters simply dislike the question content - I know there's several users  who strongly oppose lore questions, even though they're perfectly on topic. I personally don't see anything wrong with the question - it's understandable (could use minor editing but nothing serious), focused, and it's not [Bad Subjective](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) (though it is admittedly a little open to speculation).

Comment: For what it's worth, both [Skyward Sword](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/38308/47878) and [Majora's Mask](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/204825/47878) also had questions asking where they fell in the Zelda timeline.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Now that the game is out, that question seems completely fine. You have significantly more upvotes than downvotes now, demonstrating this.

As Mage Xy mentioned in a comment, there's a segment of our user base that strongly dislikes any question that is not mechanical in nature. We've had a number of <s>arguments</s> discussions about it on meta. The conclusion has been that "lore" questions are definitely on topic, but you're probably going to get some downvotes from people who wish they weren't.

Here are some relevant questions you can look over:

- [Should lore questions as an entire category be banned?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7696/108003)
- [Can I make questions about lore in Arqade?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5522/108003)
- [Could we add explicit language in the FAQ section to allow questions relating to lore?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11360/108003)

To try to understand the viewpoint of those who dislike these questions, take a look at [Frank's answer to the first one](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7702/108003). Note that all of the "bad" question examples cited in that answer have more upvotes than downvotes, but they *do* all have downvotes.