# How do we deal with new questions about game versions that are no longer available legally?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

...like [this one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/322902/where-is-the-spirit-healer-in-the-blasted-lands-vanilla)?

As it seems it is not clear how to deal with questions when the game version is outdated and the question is *new*.

In terms of WoW I strongly advise to close questions like that as Off-Topic, because it's just not possible to play the game legally in that state (vanilla or old expansions). When Blizzard opens their new Classic realms we can at least accept those questions again, but until then it's just not possible to play classic/vanilla WoW legally.

- WoW can only be played in its current state (latest expansion and patch applied) and until then the client will tell you to update the game
- Vanilla WoW was playable until 2007 when BC was released
- The vanilla client will still try to connect to old Blizzard services, which have been migrated long ago
- You can not create a private game locally
- Creating private servers is against the ToS, [even if they're offline](https://eu.battle.net/forums/en/wow/topic/3553600968#post-14)
- Joining them is against the ToS even twice

Comment: IIRC - 1) Games that are no longer playable at all - leave the questions alone ([Relevant Meta](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5565/what-do-we-do-with-questions-about-games-that-can-no-longer-be-played)) 2) Game *versions* which have major functionality changes, but which the game is still active - update or delete out of date content.

Comment: Questions that are asked *now* for games not being playable legally for 10 years should stay open? They're more than obviously about pirated game servers.

Comment: In *that* case where it's blatantly obvious they're using a pirate server - close as 'unreleased/illegal'.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're combining two different things into one post here.

**This specific question** is about playing on an illegal server. There's no indication that the question was about playing the game 10 years ago. It's clearly stated in the question "because it's vanilla", which is not possible. So I would vote to close the question as illegal content.

Your more generic *title* of your meta post is about questions regarding games which can no longer be played, which I think is different than the issue stated in the *question*. Games that are no longer playable are **legal** questions and should be left alone (see Robotnik's comment and relevant meta).

Comment: Sorry for the misleading title..Robotnik already edited it to be more clearly. The question is indeed about new questions about old game content. I know old questions about old content are legal, since we already have a meta about this.