# Should I approve suggested edits that I don't know if they are true?

Tags: discussion, reviewing

Sometimes when I go to review suggested edits I get an edit that is legitimate if true, but I don't know if it's true or not, as it addresses a game or a platform I haven't played. For example:

- When an answer says that the solution is in some menu and the edit writes how to open that menu.
- If the edit adds updated information (since update 1.4 this feature was added to the game)
- Fixing/adding information (change of "the drop rate is 15%" to "the drop rate is 14%")

Should I approve those edits assuming they are true, or should I skip them and let someone who has the necessary knowledge/experience to review them?

Comment: Can you?  Yes.  *Should* you?  No.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

No, you should not. Skip them and let somebody with a clue decide if the addition makes sense or not.

I skip many such edit suggestions myself.

Comment: This is pretty much exactly how I handle review/SE.

Comment: Or: do some research, find out whether they're true or not, then approve/reject as appropriate.