# Why was this question re-closed?

Tags: discussion, closing, reopen

[129350](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/129350/) (" [diablo-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-3)How is loot shared on D3 console co-op?") was put on hold today, with the following close reasons given:

> - "Questions about unreleased or illegal content are off topic on Arqade. We only support questions about games available to the general public through legitimate means." – LessPop_MoreFizz, fbueckert, kalina, spartacus
> - This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a game that has not been released yet. - Unionhawk

Prior to that, it had been [reopened](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/129350/revisions):

> **Post Reopened** by TZHX, galacticninja, kalina, Robotnik, fredley

Now, as per [Meta 6971](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6971/6973#6973), we decided that we would not reopen questions about unreleased games, even after the game is released. This time, however, it *was* reopened, and now we suddenly re-close it, although it is *now* a valid question?

Could we please point out precisely what we should do in such a situation?

---

The question was now also [re-asked](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/129762/) (129762, "[diablo-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-3)How is loot shared on console-based co-op play?"). What should we do about *that*, then?

Comment: The problem with leaving it reopened is we are basically letting 5 random 3kers invalidate an entire meta topic.

Comment: The problem in this case is that the question should have been deleted, after being closed, as per Badp's response to that meta.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot I would consider this more of an exceptional situation than something that completely invalidates our existing intents and policies.

Comment: We don't act on what "should have" happened, though. It hasn't happened, and this means we re-evaluate the question as it is *right now* (well, not anymore), after being reopened. (Which, btw, is why I'm not in favour of re-reopening it now either.) It was reopened, and at that point it was a valid question. Instead, it was re-closed, mainly to "correct the mistake that was made", regardless of the actual question.

Comment: @GraceNote It changes "Site policy is to do X" into "Site policy is to do X unless it gets overlooked and then it is fine."

Comment: If site policy is to close questions that are otherwise valid because we don't like the method in which they became valid, maybe site policy has a problem. Sure, the question should have been deleted and thus never reopened. We failed to do that. The proper response is to suck it up and try harder to get things deleted next time, not close a *now completely valid question* because we don't like the question ID attached to it.

Comment: @Sterno We don't like question IDs now?  Be right back, VTCing every question that ends with a seven.

Comment: @fbueckert If you're closing based on asked date *after the fact*, that's pretty much the same as closing by ID.

Comment: @FEichinger Not really, it's just being consistent.

Comment: So to summarise, the question should have been deleted, **but wasn't**. It became 'valid' (as per the game's release) and was then reopened, **but shouldn't have been**. It was then re-closed, **but shouldn't have been.** Personally, I don't think the evil 'question camping' is that big of a problem *in this case* as it's made out to be. Sure, this question should've been deleted. Sure, our ongoing policy should be to close camping questions (because camping is **bad**). But as for this question/corner case? Are we really going to remove a valid question for the sake of consistency?

Comment: @Robotnik My meta answer covers the "What if it wasn't camping?" argument.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot It does, luckily I wasn't making that argument :P. As I've said I'm in agreement with everything on your answer there. Camping is bad and they should feel bad. In this particular corner case however, the question was left alone to suddenly become quite valid. It should've stayed closed, but once it was reopened, it should've remained that way. Now it's in contention, and it is a reasonably good question in and of itself, so it's my view that it should be re-reopened. *This is not, and should not be the case for every question asked that camps unlreleased games*

Comment: @Robotnik Then you should know that leaving it open is rewarding rule breakers.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot And yet, if the same person asked it again, it would be fine.

Comment: @FEichinger No one ever said rule breakers can't become rule followers.

Comment: I apologise for my input into getting this reopened, I did not remember the site policy to remove posts that were valid questions but asked before the game was released.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot - Sometimes rules need to be bent a little

Comment: @kalina That's because it's not the site policy- I don't see any rationale here behind the question being closed to begin with.

Comment: @Decency [But it *is* site policy.](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4523/how-do-i-know-if-i-should-move-forward-with-something-that-was-discussed-on-meta) Not all policies are going to be in the FAQ. That's why we have tags on Meta.

Answer (score 11):

There's a few of reasons we have this "no pre-release questions" policy, attached to it rulings about reopening things when time hits. Some are political, others are quite mechanical.

- It's an invalid question at the time it is asked. We cannot field a question before the game's release, so it counts as a future point in time and is pointedly off-topic for the site.
- It's unfair to "seed" questions ahead of time, especially potentially valuable questions. This is less why we have the policy and more why we have stock in the policy, if that makes sense. If a question is indeed valuable, then it will naturally get asked post-release.
- Mechanically, it's a complete waste of everyone's time. A question asked after the release is no cost. Asked before the release, you have 5 people voting to close and then you have 5 people waiting to vote to reopen on the release date. The end results are identical, but we have more work to do that we have absolutely no obligation to perform for anyone.

The entire scenario is not ideal, but the ideal manifestation is that when a question gets closed as such, like a properly off-topic question, it should be deleted.

This didn't happen. So we have a furthermore less-than-ideal scenario on our shoulders. Made further less ideal by people voting to reopen, though it is their vote to have used and while I personally feel that it's somewhat mediocre to do, it is time spent and gone with. So how do we progress with this? Let's review the reasons.

- It is no longer an invalid question once we hit the release date. It is in fact a valid question.
- It may be a seed question, but everyone who spent their time reopening it, had all their opportunity to have asked it on their own. They chose to instead reopen it because at this stage, we have the question and it is in a fit state.
- *Any further action is even more of a waste of time*. Closing it again, reopening it again, even having this debate at all is a humongous waste of everyone's time for pretty much no good reason. The letter of our policy isn't undermined because we choose to listen to the spirit of the policy. Likewise, the spirit of the policy isn't wholly undermined because we choose to obey the letter of our policy.

Both sides of this argument have been correct. We're indeed screwing up in all directions. Reopening broke the letter of policy. Reclosing broke the spirit of policy. 
At this stage, the original is now closed and we now have a newly asked version here: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/129762/how-is-loot-shared-on-console-based-co-op-play. The whole thing is breaking things all over the place, so it's essentially an outside component to the whole of how our site works.

At this stage, **keeping a live, valid question on the site has far exceeded anything about how it interacted with our policies to reach this stage**. It cannot serve as an example of how this kind of situation can be resolved, it should not serve as such, it does not influence our ability to handle further breaches of policy. What we have is (assumedly, at least) valuable content and at this point, any further discussion or thought on its *history* is a waste of everyone's time and counterproductive towards the goals of everyone involved.

The entirety of our site is founded towards the production of content. It's our very mission, after all. Policy is important for allowing us to maintain our quality of content, and the livelihood of our site. I don't think for a moment that this kind of slip hampers the intent of policy, even if its history disregards policy entirely at this stage. Because at this stage, what we have is a question that, in some fashion, got asked, and we already squandered enough time discussing policy against content, further would be even more waste.

Comment: So to confirm: you believe the question should be reopened, and the post-facto duplicate deleted?

Comment: @Raven I would've gone with whichever one was open and simply leave it at that. Now that we're at the stage of all things closed again... one should be opened and the other should be eliminated. My personal position is that this stage, it doesn't matter which one is open because the sense of the policy has long been lost in this debacle and all that remains now is to retain the content we need. For ease of sake let's go with what you suggested.

Answer (score -5):

There is an obvious failure here of basic reading comprehension. The FAQ forbids ***speculation*** about unreleased games. Just because a game hasn't been released yet doesn't mean that every question about that game can only have unknowable or speculative answers.

In this case, the question already had an official answer from a Blizzard Community Manager [here](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/9244644870#4) from almost three months ago. I see no reason why this question would thus be considered anything other than a valid and answerable question- OrigamiRobot's [answer](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6973/11047) in the linked meta explictly makes an assumption that simply does not apply here.

Comment: [Relevant to this issue.](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/7299/14775)

Comment: A question being answerable prior to release does not automatically make it on-topic.  We've been over that exact point several times before.

Comment: @Fluttershy Relevant, but entirely contradictory to both the FAQ and the meta discussion [here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5539/when-is-a-game-publicly-available) where the community rather clearly decides that questions about unreleased games are fine as long as they have definitive and well-evidenced answers.

Comment: @fbueckert Feel free to link to any of those discussions.

Comment: @Decency The discussion here is the exception, not the rule. This was a special case in which the community and moderators didn't act in a timely manner, causing quite a bit of confusion.

Comment: @Fluttershy You can discuss the exception to the rule here if you'd like, but it's about as obvious as it gets that the question being discussed here isn't an example of that exception. There was no necessary action on the question to begin with.

Comment: Well, for one, it's right in one of our custom off-topic reasons: "Questions about unreleased or illegal content are off topic on Arqade."  We make an exception for questions about pre-order details, but everything else is subject to change, regardless of whether or not there's an official answer.  It's carried under, "Speculation of the future of the industry."

Comment: @fbueckert As I said, feel free to link to one of those **discussions**. An oversight by a moderator when adding new close reasons doesn't overrule an overwhelming majority opinion on an already discussed issue.

Comment: You're free to find them on your own; I'm not tying your hands.  I'm pointing out what is considered common knowledge by the community, and why.  You're also free to make another Meta post about it if you like.

Comment: @fbueckert Translation: there aren't any.

Comment: @fbueckert - If you are the one making a point, you have the burden of proof. Our entire site revolves around questions & answers that can be backed up by relevant sources. Otherwise, the Q&As get downvoted for poor research effort.

Comment: @Decency There's a reason many of us have stopped using the word 'speculation' - it's because it's ambiguous and opens up arguments about whether a question is on topic based on it's answerability, which ought *never* be the measurement by which we determine a questions appropriateness. It was a poor choice of language when the subject was first raised, and being persnickity about that particular word choice is defeating the spirit of the rule by arguing the letter.

Comment: @Decency Close reasons were submitted by and voted by the community. I can confirm however that we do ___not___ want questions about unreleased anything, no matter how much official information there is about it, because 1. that's what news sites are for, and we aren't one and 2. no matter how official a pre-release comment can be, companies can always change their minds and 180-spin on it (see also: XBox One.)

Comment: Relevant to this would be LessPop and my answers [over to this Meta question](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7286/what-is-considered-future-here), wherein we both touch on the subject of not-yet-released stuff. Our words there are pretty relevant to our policy regarding this.

Comment: @badp If you're going to entirely 180 with previously (heavily) agreed upon rules, you might want to inform the community or at the very least update the help page about what questions can be asked. As the rules are written currently, the question is an excellent fit for the site.

Comment: @badp You even acknowledged in the question yourself that the proposed rule in question "is kinda wrong".

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz The rule is in place so people don't ask questions that will garner speculative answers. This concern (the "spirit" of the rule) is described explicitly by various users in about a dozen places that have already been linked to above. This question is not speculative, it has an authoritative answer, it's not "news", and it's not a clear attempt to park a topic. A weak attempt to make the rule black-and-white just alienates plenty of valid, answerable, and interesting questions such as this one.

Comment: @GraceNote The question being discussed is about a core gameplay mechanic. I think you'd be hard pressed to call that news.

Comment: @Decency The meta answer you referred to way back at the beginning clearly says "If a "pre-release" question about a game can be asked and answered without speculation __because an alpha/beta/early version exists__"  That was not the case for this question and is therefore not applicable.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot Looks almost right when you take it out of context. Not so much when you include the entirety: **If a "pre-release" question about a game can be asked and answered without speculation because an alpha/beta/early version exists, regardless of the number of people who are/could be in possession of said game, it should be left open.** Nevermind that of course an alpha version of the game existed at that point- alpha releases are generally internal.

Comment: To clarify my answer/comments in the other meta, the intent there is to not forbid questions that users of the site have while playing limited releases of games.  Essentially, I don't want to draw a line at the release date and say "before this line is speculation, and after is not" when that doesn't always make sense.  The role of "answerability" in allowing questions is a muddy gray area, though, and I think often we end up stuck in minefields with no good, consistent way to handle situations.

Comment: In this particular case, the user isn't playing a prerelease of the console version and asking a question about their experiences, they're asking for details on an unreleased game.  But then there *is* an official answer before release.  So it's a mess, essentially.  I wish I had an easy answer for these situations, but there's a mess no matter how it's handled.

Comment: In my opinion, there's a fundamental problem with needing to know the answer to a question before deciding whether or not it should be left open or closed. I've repeated this point in a bunch of different meta discussions recently. In this particular case, developers/marketing/whatever had an answer, but having to go look and find out there is one is a poor measure of determining whether or not the question should be left open.

Comment: @Sterno I think there's a fundamental problem with the community when adding difficulty to closing questions is ranked as a more pressing concern than adding difficulty to answering questions.

Comment: @Sterno, this is something I've dealt with in the past as well.  In other policy decisions, we've erred on the side of 'close em all, let Zeus sort em out.'  (See also: the "why did they design it that way" discussion, the "plot and trivia" discussion, etc)  I don't really like any of the "reasonable to implement" solutions on offer, honestly.

Comment: @Decency Way to cherrypick. The [full comment](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7295/what-will-be-our-custom-off-topic-close-reasons/7299#comment20274_7299) reads "#2 is kinda wrong, _private betas are okay_". That's nothing to do with unreleased games.

Comment: ...and by _private betas_ we do ___not___ mean internal-consumption-only or press-only private builds of the game; merely versions of the game that are _released_ to the _public_ on an _invitational_ basis so that people can answer questions based on the version of the game they are actually _playing_, as explained  [here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5539/when-is-a-game-publicly-available#comment16461_5541).

Comment: @Decency for what it's worth, I have no horse in this race. Close 'em all. Leave 'me all open. I don't care much in this case. Pick whether or not a question category is on or off topic for the site and go with it. Either way it goes, lets just make sure policy doesn't require arguments about if it should be opened or closed every single time one of the questions of that type come up. That just fills the question comments with argument.

Comment: @badp The point stands: the close reason does not align with existing policy before adding the close reason.

Comment: @badp Also, the "publicly available" policy that keeps being repeated has no basis anywhere I've yet seen. I asked almost a year ago [here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5539/when-is-a-game-publicly-available#comment16400_5539) and got no answer then either. Agent's comment refers to **speculative** questions. Personally, I don't see a problem with answerable non-speculative questions about games that are near to release even if they're entirely private. Those aren't common, but this is a pretty clear example of one that has value. And if it's not answerable until later, fine.

Comment: @Decency I've just linked to it.

Comment: @badp You realize that I also just linked to me asking in that question where the publicly available policy comes from, right?

Comment: @dec well, that is a +20-odd post explaining the policy you're asking about. There's no need to go deeper :-)

Comment: @badp Yes, the same +20-odd post that your change to close reasons effectively refutes. Solid consistency with the rules there!

Comment: @Decency You'll have to spell out the contradiction here, for I am too dumb to see it.

Comment: @badp You're citing a post as site-policy while at the same time you've preempted the main argument in that post by adding close reasons that simply do not agree with it.

Comment: @Decency Again I do not see the disagreement with the close reasons I didn't write. A beta can be available to the general public, while remaining private to a closed group of users - like the Dota 2 private beta was. Internal builds of games aren't available to the public and, as that post and comments on it argue, we don't want any of that.

Comment: @Decency For the record I've always considered the "beta" exception to be a convenient contradiction born out of previous contests.  Content generated from betas is no less vulnerable to rot than official statements that are pre-release.  Betas exist so that things can be tuned, and game mechanics are often changed.  Personally I wish we'd get real in general about the fact that game content changes...  just about anything will get stale if we don't act to maintain it.

Comment: [Another example](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7053/bioshock-infinite-closures-on-release-day) of our pre-release policy at work.  Along the lines of @GraceNote 's answer - I wonder if we don't spend more time fretting about this policy then the policy itself saves.

Comment: @EBongo Yep, it's mostly just policy for the sake of policy. Whatever makes people feel like they're contributing to maintaining the status quo, I guess.