# Why was this COD WWII question deleted?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, specific-question, deleted-questions

I understand why [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/320600/32055) (about a soon-to-be-released but not-yet-released game) was *closed* (although I think it was a bit inconsistent, since there are several other questions about the game that are open, upvoted, and/or have answers). I had planned to try to get it re-opened once the game is released (tomorrow), but I just noticed that it has also been deleted.

Once the game is released, the question should be on-topic, correct? Are there other issues with it that necessitate its removal?

This was the question:

> **What splitscreen options are available in Call of Duty World War II? [closed]**
>
> How many players can play split-screen, and what game modes are (or aren't) available?
>   •How many players can play local co-op?
>   •How many players can play local multiplayer?
>   •How many players can play online multiplayer from a single console?
>
> These questions don't appear to be specifically addressed anywhere on the website, and I didn't see any mention in any of the reviews I've read. Even the packaging of the game itself (I haven't seen it, basing this claim off of the standard Xbox One game packaging details) only answers the first of these three questions.

Comment: Related: https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6971/should-we-reopen-questions-being-closed-for-unreleased-game-after-the-game-is

Comment: @Unionhawk interesting. I hadn't considered the "parking" aspect; I had hoped that since there had been a (public?) beta and there were existing questions that I'd just get an answer from someone who has played. Based on the answers to that question, it seems I should re-ask tomorrow rather than get my original undeleted/reopened.

Comment: How does 'parking/camping' work? I am not familiar with the terminology.

Comment: @Childishforlife the accepted answer on the related question explains it.

Comment: @yoozer8 he mentions that people who "re-open and get all the rep". Does this refer to nobody else being able to ask that question, because it has already been asked and can't be re-asked by somebody else?

Comment: Next time (now isn't too late either) please add the full text of the question to your meta post, especially if it's been deleted. People can't discuss what they can't see, can they?