# Using code ticks for technical term highlighting considered harmful

Tags: discussion, site-policies, editing

Lots of users across the Stack Exchange network have developed a habit of using code markup (backticks in Markdown) to give technical terms special formatting that stands out visually. This only seems to happen on sites that don't actually deal with code snippets, since "there's no other use for it."

For example:

> To defeat Gannon's second form you need to use the `bow` and `dark arrows` until he turns purple, then use the `bombs of time`.

which renders into the HTML page* as:

```
To defeat Gannon's second form you need to use the <code>bow</code>
and <code>dark arrows</code> until he turns purple, then use the
<code>bombs of time</code>.
```

The problem with this is that code tags are *semantic markup* in HTML and they're rendered differently than the writer might expect in other contexts. This can result in problems like [visually imparied users hearing random words spelled out while the page is rendered by their screen reading software](http://accessibility.psu.edu/boldface).**

Visual users might like how it looks, but it is abusing the standard in a way that can impair other users to a lesser or greater degree. I know that we can't prevent someone new from mangling formatting, but I would like the support of experienced editors in eliminating this very common abuse of semantic markup. Bold and italics are semantic markup that mean "give this emphasis", which is correctly rendered in the way usually intended for technical terms in all contexts, so we should only ever used bold or italics for technical terms.

The example above using the better markup (if any is needed at all):

> To defeat Gannon's second form you need to use the **bow** and **dark arrows** until he turns purple, then use the **bombs of time**.

And another example of correct semantic formatting:

> The content of the leaderboard is saved to `%appdata%\awesomegame\lb.dat` every ten minutes.

Doing this requires no technical changes, only the will of the editing community here to make it standard practice.

Can we, as a community, support the correct use of semantic formatting markup on Arqade?†

---

* You can verify this in Firefox by highlighting the example and right clicking the selected text, and choosing *View Selection Source* from the context menu.

** It might seem at first glance as if this problem can be avoided by configuring the screen reader to read code tags as normal text, but then this will mangle text in code tags that is supposed to be spelled out. For a minimal example of a formatted sentence that *cannot* be correctly rendered by a screen reader under any configuration, consider:

> Type `xyzzy` then use the `bow`.

Either "xyzzy" will be incorrectly read as a word and "bow" will be read correctly, or "xyzzy" will be read spelled-out correctly and "bow" will also be spelled out incorrectly. There is no way for a screen reader to read the mind of the writer to find out what was intended, which is why code tags were invented in the first place – to tell a computer what meaning is intended. To indicate what we *intend* the text to mean we can leverage semantic HTML instead of fighting with it, and rewrite the sentence above to any of these:

> Type `xyzzy` then use the **bow**.
>   Type `xyzzy` then use the *bow*.
>   Type `xyzzy` then use the bow.

† This has also been discussed on MSO: [Inline Code Spans should not be used for emphasis, right?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135112/inline-code-spans-should-not-be-used-for-emphasis-right)

Comment: +1 I agree, although I'd like to define where we draw the line. technical terms such as  **20Gb**, *RAM*, *Lag* should be bold or italicised (if needed at all), whereas command lines & filepaths should still be in code ticks (such as `C:\Program Files` or `java Example.java`). Is this what you were getting at?

Comment: @Robotnik Exactly! Those are the sorts of things that semantic code formatting are for. Anything intending to be a precise text input to a computer should be in code formatting.

Comment: Your link on screen reading software contains no information about screen reading software?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I'm not sure I fully follow what you're asking. Could you post an example of what not to do? Do it as a screenshot if you're worried about causing the same problem with your meta post. :P

Comment: @None Is that really an assumption we should be making? There are people who are unable to read text comfortably (so may use screen readers) who can play video games; are they unwelcome? What about people using accessibility software to play text adventures? So there are two off the top of my head. Does misusing code formatting provide so much benefit that it's worth frustrating even one gamer with a disability?

Comment: @jack The link talks about the semantic definition of HTML formatting. The code tag is "semantically designated to spell out code". Unless we're going to go out and buy a lot of screen readers and do testing in them to make sure they all handle inappropriate use if code formatting cleverly, we should format to the HTML spec – that's what it's for, after all.

Comment: @Sterno Added some examples at your request! Do those clarify things?

Comment: `I don't see what the problem is.`

Comment: @NickT Hah, sighted person joke. Very funny.

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness It's not about the users, it's about complying with the standard that is set. The users are merely the reason the standard exists and should be followed to begin with.

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness For the same reason that we don't use bold for headers, don't use `<br><br>` for paragraph breaks, and don't make something an empty link just to get a pretty blue colour. HTML tags have meanings, and misusing them makes the Internet worse. Our mission is to make the Internet better.

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness Please make your comment an answer so I can downvote it.

Comment: @Seven You mistake the markup language of arqade for html.

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness Markdown is converted into HTML for the browser to display. What you type is not the actual output - the actual output is what concerns us, though.

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness You seem to care strongly about this, but you haven't yet articulated what your stake in this is. Is there a compelling reason you see to use HTML `<code></code>` tags (aka, Markdown backticks) for non-code on Arqade that I'm missing?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: You made a rather specific claim about screen reader software though. I'd like to see evidence for your problem which the link you give does not provide.

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness: No, it's not okay to ignore blind users. If this is really a problem then a solution is needed (although it could easily be in the software rather than user base). Unfortunately, no evidence of a problem is presented in the OP.

Comment: @JackAidley - It's a problem so long as there is a single vision-impaired person on this planet. It's the same reason why new buildings are now mandated to have easy access for wheelchairs. There aren't as strict guidelines on the internet, however we should be doing everything within our power anyway to make the web a more accessible place. Avoiding backticks for emphasis is a small but powerful way this site can bring better access to this site for those with impaired vision.

Comment: So, If I am understanding the issue seven is raising here, to a screen reader the above Gannon example using code ticks would sound something like "To defeat Gannon's second form you need to use the **bee-oh-doubleU** and **dee-ay-are-kay-space-ay-are-are-oh-doubleU-ess** until he turns purple, then use the **bee-oh-em-bee-ess-space-oh-eff-space-tea-eye-em-ee**", correct?

Comment: @TrentHawkins - I haven't used a screen reader myself, but I daresay it's probably closer to: "...you need to use the **Begin code block. Bee-Oh-DoubleU. End Code Block** until he turns purple..."

Comment: @Robotnik Aah, yeah - I can certainly get behind not using code ticks for emphasis then.

Comment: @Trent It depends how it's configured. The problem is that the reader isn't psychic and relies on the tags, so it will always read "type `xyzzy` then use the `bow`" wrong, because `xyzzy` should be spelled and "bow" should be pronounced as a word. With both in code ticks, every screen reader configuration will mangle one or the other because garbage in, garbage out. It should be "type `xyzzy` then use the **bow**" so they can be handled differently if the user wants them handled differently.

Comment: Heh, I only just saw this. Let it be known that on (Meta) Stack Overflow I'm incredibly vocal about this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137755/reject-an-already-approved-suggested-edit-when-rolling-it-back

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness That is 100% false.

Comment: @TheAnnoyingPyro Thanks for the link! That also lead to [this MSO discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135112/inline-code-spans-should-not-be-used-for-emphasis-right) where it's directly discussed.

Comment: [Here's a query](http://data.stackexchange.com/gaming/query/edit/128283) to find your posts that contain `<code>`.  Go nuts.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Is the use of code markup for tables generally considered acceptable? We otherwise have no table support on the site, and after running MBraedley's query, I noticed that it was the majority of my personal usage.

Comment: @FAE Yes! You had me worried for a moment while I considered that. The way we do tables actually uses the `pre` tag under the hood—it looks the same as code formatting to us, but semantically those tags don't mark it as code, they mark it as "precomposed" layout. So yes, that's safe and correct use of the monospaced block formatting. (It does make me wonder how we're *supposed* to designate large blocks of text as code, but that's an HTML spec problem, not ours.) It should probably be removed from the query.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie [HTML specification for the code tag](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/text-level-semantics.html#the-code-element) - As per this, a block of code is to be enclosed in both `pre` and `code`, with `code` being the inner.

Comment: @FEichinger Ah, which is hard to do in markdown. Interesting.

Comment: Well, we could always add support for the mark HTML tag: [mark tag explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/mark)

Answer (score 30):

`<em>` and `<strong>` are [in the list of whitelisted tags that can be used on *Stack Exchange*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites/135909#135909). Go mad. If you want more, I suggest you ask for your specific tag to be whitelisted on MSO.

While you're at it, please destroy all misuse of backticks for emphasis, because they're an abuse of formatting. MBraedley has provided a [query](http://data.stackexchange.com/gaming/query/edit/128283) to check your own posts that contain code markup.

Comment: I know it's not an Arqade-only problem, but the local Metas are where a site's active editors will see it, and it's *them* that I want to reach rather than those who follow the rarified policy discussions of MSO. They're not rank-and-file editors who can make a practical difference on a site.

Comment: This is a problem specific to non-technical sites. Arqade being one of those, I find this very appropriate here. Of course there are other sites where it also applies, but it's surely not a problem that should be dealt with on an overreaching capacity.

Comment: @FEichinger That's an excellent point. In an old discussion of this on RPG.SE, the fact that there was no other use for code formatting was used as an argument for reappropriating it to visually format game technical terms.

Comment: @FEichinger - As long as we continue to support troubleshooting, I would still consider us a technical site.

Comment: @Robotnik At the core, we are not. Technical questions on Arqade - unlike SO, SU or SF - are secondary. There's also no harm in using backticks for *actual code* (f.e. the process name, a console command, etc) - not for jargon.

Comment: @FEichinger - At the core, we provide expert answers to questions. (at least, that's our mission). This would be a very different place if it were more similar to SciFi & Fantasy, or Movies & TV - in that we only answered gameplay/storyline problems. There is a level of technical knowledge needed to be a gamer - stuff like knowing how a computer works, what a stacktrace is and what it means (and how to fix or work around it) - It's that knowledge which I believe plays a big role in this site, and for that reason I would still consider us a technical site.

Comment: All of this is really irrelevant. If you want to add a tag to the whitelist you're going to have more luck on MSO. Editors can't do that for you and editors already know better from what I've seen than to abuse backticks. Technical or not technical, any site may benefit from having, say, `em` whitelisted.

Comment: @badp I'm not sure what you're referring to when you mention whitelists. It sounds like some kind of SE platform feature? What I'm proposing isn't something the platform can help with, so perhaps we have a misunderstanding? As for editors knowing better, I see it semi-regularly here. Today's inspiration for this post was a 1k user's answer misusing code ticks, then a 10k user who did a formatting edit on it but left the code ticks intact.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie You ask "Can we support the correct use of semantic formatting markup on Arqade?" That is a platform feature. You can see the whitelist of supported tags [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135909/13992).

Comment: @badp You're misunderstanding the post here. This isn't about adding a tag/markup, it's about editing posts to ensure appropriate use of an existing tag/markup.

Comment: Yes, I think we misunderstand each other. :) `em` and `strong` are already what `*` and `**` produce, so we're already using semantic tags and don't need any others made available. We just need to use them for their intended purposes to respect the spec.

Comment: @badp I think you're confused with your first paragraph.  He's not asking to have any new tags whitelisted, or to start using `<em>` or `<strong>` in posts *(that's already being done - `*text*` and `<em>text</em>` produce equivalent output, as do `**text**` and `<strong>text</strong>`)*.  *"Please destroy all misuse of backticks for emphasis"* is, however, exactly what he's asking for, for the reason you mention and also because it apparently confuses screen-readers.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft: The claim that it confuses screen readers is, however, totally unsupported and isn't any more true for this use of the code ticks than for their correct use. If it is an issue for screen readers - which I doubt - then it's a bug that needs correcting in either screen reader or the StackExchange code base. The Screen Reader issue is a total red herring.

Answer (score -6):

I personally don't use code ticks in this wrong manner, atleast not that I can recall - it could've happened by mistake :P. Sure, I can get behind a campaign to try and stop abusing code tags, and I do support this idea in principle.

But frankly, if we're worried about screen readers then a major problem in Arqade and other sites is how often useful nuggets of data are buried deep in comments or across multiple answers. This is probably far more frustrating for listeners than having to put up with a few words being spelled out.

As an obvious example, the question and answers above : how much context would be lost if you ignored the parade of comments attached? I have also often added answers that reference existing ones (via a link) and just expanded on them with more information.

In summary, while its a nice idea in principle I'm unconvinced of actual usability benefits; people with visual readers don't have a problem while those using screen readers have far worse structural challenges to deal with before running into this.

Comment: Comments on meta are not comparable to comments on main. Do we have a problem with good info buried in comments on main? It's standard procedure to edit those into the questions/answers and then flag them as obsolete, so you can just do that when you find them.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Didn't know the policy is to edit them into answer, does this apply to all sites? Because yes, I have noticed this problem but mostly on Arqade (because I frequent it more often, no idea if main SE site is better or worse)

Answer (score -28):

Hmm.. if the problem you claim - "visually imparied users hearing random words spelled out while the page is rendered by their screen reading software" - is real (there's absolutely zero support for it in your link) then it should be a problem that is occurring with StackOverflow and the original usage of the code ticks too. There's no reason `int` should be fine but `zorg breeder` should cause a problem.

That being the case then this is either a problem that needs to be solved at the software level for the good of StackExchange overall, a bug in a specific screen reader, or your given reason isn't actually a reason at all.

Without an accessibility reason not to do so this simply comes down to subjective preference and that, frankly, is the kind of thing for the community to settle on standards for rather than something that needs imposing.

Comment: HTML is a semantic markdown language. It's as simple as that. The tag is called "code" because it is supposed to contain exactly that: code. Various software relies on this to be *correct*. A bunch of tags were even deprecated and replaced by new tags to enhance this part of the language (`b` -> `strong` and `i` -> `em` being prominent examples). It does not matter whether the specific example given is an issue, it is a matter of complying with existing standards of the underlying architecture. There is nothing wrong with SE's implementation of Markdown, it's the usage that is incorrect.

Comment: @FEichinger is exactly right. It's not a bug, it's misuse. It would be like a blind user making a page with white text on a white background: both colour choices are valid, and *they* can read it, but it is not a *good* choice because it makes it inaccessible to visual readers.

Comment: Unless the semantics are actually causing a problem though - something @SevenSidedDie has simply failed to demonstrate, it's completely irrelevant. Correctness on this point is just pedantry. It does not matter to the operation of the site one jot. Therefore, the only question is whether the misuse is useful to members of the site.

Comment: @FEichinger: If, as SevenSidedDie claimed unsupported by the link they gave, Screen Readers are misreading code tags then that is a bug either in the screen reader or SE's code. Even if I right `int` - a semantically correct usage of the code ticks - then the screen reader will read it in an exactly the same way as if I use it for `zorg breeder` - a semantically incorrect way - thus any issue with screen reader software is not a problem with the misuse of the tag but a bug in either SE or screen reader.

Comment: @JackAidley They are not *misreading* the code tags. They are *interpreting code tags as code*. "zorg breeder" is not code and should not be in there. What's so hard about that?

Comment: @FEichinger: SevenSidedDie in the opening message claimed "visually imparied users hearing random words spelled out while the page is rendered by their screen reading software" - this is misreading the code tags. It is _also_ totally unsupported by the link given. _If_ it occurs then it's a problem _but_ it's not a problem that is unique to the misuse of code ticks. That being the case it does not provide support either way to whether code ticks should be used here for non-code since it's a bug with semantically correct use of code ticks too.

Comment: @JackAidley No, that is the **intended behavior** for code - Code cannot - and should not - be "read" like normal text. But as I said before, this is completely irrelevant. This is about **complying with [existing standards](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#semantics-0)**. This neither affects *only* screen readers, nor does it primarily affect screen readers - they are just one type of thing that relies on the correct usage of semantic HTML.

Comment: The code ticks tag is _intended_ to be read inline e.g. "No, you need to make `mGigglyBits` an `int` array for that to work". That's the _entire point_ of the code tick tags. Again *if* (no actual evidence of a problem has yet been presented) they're being wrongly dealt with by screen readers then that is either (a) a bug in SE or (b) a bug in the screen reader. It is categorically _not_ a Arqade specific problem. That being so bringing it in the argument is a complete red herring because it's a problem for their _intended_ usage as well as the Arqade specific usage. What's so hard about that?

Comment: Why would this be a bug in SE? Markdown turns backticks into `<code></code>`, which is *perfectly correct*. Screen readers then interpret this as *code* - Arqade, however (and a lot of other non-technical SE sites) misuse backticks for emphasis. That is *semantically incorrect*. Code is neither emphasised, nor is it interpreted by semantic-safe parsers as such. [Google published a note on this](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.de/2012/07/on-web-semantics.html) just as well. The problem is caused by content creators, not by the software.

Comment: @FEichinger: Does it cause words to be read out of order? That being the _claim made in the original post_ that I'm responding to. That **IS A BUG BECAUSE IT'S WRONG IN THE INTENDED USE AS WELL**.

Comment: That is **completely irrelevant**, though. It may be incorrectly worded, but it has **no bearing whatsoever** on the fact that we should be **complying with semantic HTML**.

Comment: It's the argument being put forth. It's completely irrelevant then that's SevenSidedDie's fault for raising that particular - rather weak - argument in the first place.

Comment: The, different, argument that it violates semantics is valid. But it's a very weak argument, because it's blatantly obvious that both you, and the rest of Arqade's users, are actually perfectly capable of understanding and - since the OP's claim of screen reader problems is totally unsupported - there's no reason to believe it's a special problem for blind readers.

Comment: @Jack You misunderstand the argument being put forth. I'm not saying the screen reader software malfunctions. I'm saying that lying to software has unintended consequences. Using code tags for non-code is lying to software. (We don't mistag questions, so why text?) It is incorrect usage now; it's also not future-proof to mistag content that is intended to be consumed by unknown software years and decades from now. As a second prong to the argument, right now this *may* be causing problems for minorities, which is something we should avoid doing for the mere convenience of the majority, right?

Comment: I couldn't care less about screen readers and "usability" of the the tags.  Using the monospaced font for random terms (`Sword of 1000 Truths`) just looks god-awful ugly.

Comment: @JackAidley Are you, perhaps, fixating on the phrasing "[...]random words spelled out[...]"? Because I doubt given the context it is meant to indicate that words are randomly being spelled out. But rather that to the person using a screen reader, words in the middle of a sentence are being spelled out for no discernible reason. For those of us with vision, the reason is rather obvious - code ticks make the text look different. But if we are using code tics to merely emphasize text, *we* are doing it **wrong**.