# Selecting/copying text from a code block

Tags: support

I am new to Arqade.  I am trying to learn procedures and structures here.  I have mainly only answered questions about Minecraft.  Some of the questions have included a large command in a code block, some have commands in code format but not with the scroll bar so it takes up multiple lines and some are in quote form.

In code block with the scroll bar, using the windows 10 edge browser, I have a very difficult time selecting all the text for copying.  Select all from the drop down menu selects the entire page, using home or end buttons cause page to scroll, and scrolling while selecting causes a deselection.

I currently have to select a portion, copy it, select another portion, copy it, and so on.

I have posted answers which included commands in the alternate formats to make it easier to copy for other users with the same difficulty.

I have now found the meta portion of the page to answer my more specific questions and I found [this discussion](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11524/186522).  I will now be conforming to those standards.

1. Has anyone else had the same selection difficulty?  What solutions have you come up with?
2. Should I go through my previous answers and reformat the commands so they are in code blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I decided to look into this a bit.  I tested across two browsers, Chrome and Edge.  I used [your answer for this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/312345/adding-extra-armor-points-with-attributes/312377#312377) as a example to test with. I found that:

- In Edge (version 25.10586.672), when attempting to highlight large code blocks with a scroll bar, **the scroll does not work**, making it difficult to highlight the entire block.
- In Chrome (version 59.0.3071.115), when attempting to highlight large code blocks with a scroll bar, **the scrolling works**.

This appears to be a browser limitation.  If you have another browser to test with, you can see for yourself.  One workaround I found for this in Edge is to "Edit" the post, and then copy the code from there.  It'll look a little daunting, but you should be able to.  The scrolling in Edge works for the actual Edit dialog box.

As for if you think you need to reformat your previous answers into code blocks, my general rule of thumb is if it can fit onto one or maybe two lines, then use the code ticks (`), otherwise, put it into a code block.  If you think it's worth it, you can certainly go back and change any posts. Just be mindful of how many you change at a time.  You'll wind up blowing up the active queue on the site if you do it too rapidly.

Comment: Just for fun, I checked explorer even though it is also Microsoft.  Big surprise, same problem.  I have also checked out Firefox and scrolling works with Firefox.

Comment: @IronAnvil GG Microsoft. Big surprise indeed.

Comment: Agreed.  Now that they have Minecraft, perhaps we get to wade through even more crash reports.