# Odd behaviour when adding Images

Tags: bug, status-norepro, images

I have a post that (admittedly I have attempted to add and re-add the picture) that just won't cooperate. I have tried on two different pc's, on two different networks, with no difference.

My last attempt has ended up like this:

[image]

What's going on?? I originally tried adding them "from the web", then I tried "from my computer", to no effect.

**UPDATE** The issue seems to have resolved itself, though I feel like [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239424/chat-profile-avatars-width-wrong-with-alt-text) may have had something to do with it...

Comment: It even happened here... All I can see is "Enter image description here"

Comment: Whelp - on further investigation... that's all I can see... on every post.

Comment: Are you on a corporate network? It looks like imgur is blocked on your end.

Comment: @MadScientist I was on a business network earlier today, and I'm on a Home network now, but that never had an effect before. Nothing's changed on the network settings either. I can see them on [SE Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18655) though...

Comment: Whaaaat?? [I can see this one too!](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/209406/witch-games-are-this) I don't know why??

Comment: OhhhhhKAy... Magically fixed itself... wuuut??

Comment: It wasn't just Arqade, I had the same problem with viewing images across all SE sites. It was likely a problem/glitch on Imgur's end (who host our images). On the positive side, this is the other reason why we [prefer to add actual descriptive text](http://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7470/28182) instead of leaving it as 'enter image description here' - in the case of the image not being accessible, the text will at least help to describe what was in the image.

Answer (score 2):

[status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro)

It seems like this was a one-off issue with Imgur that has since been resolved.