# A large number of my questions and answers require editing — how to approach?

Tags: support

In the past I've used my private Imgur account to embed some images in higher, lossless quality (Stack Exchange's Imgur account `stack.imgur.com` compresses images above 1 MB in size). This may result in permanent of loss of data and bandwidth usage can also be relatively high (mobile users with low-speed connections and data caps suffer in particular). The other issue is that that I used to enter a blank description for all images when I was still unaware of the drawbacks: the description is essential for screen reader users (blind and illiterate people, visually impaired) and people using a text-based web browser. There are a few dozen questions and answers with my own image host alone.

To avoid impairing the visibility of others' posts (edited posts are pushed to the top of [active category](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=active)), how many Arqade Q/A post should I modify daily, approximately?

Comment: There is no limit as to how many edits you can make a day.  The limit is how many you *should* make.  I will share with you that once I edited so many posts in a short amount of time, that moderators contacted me and asked me to slow down.  So if you are blowing up the active queue, its probably time to tone it back.  That being said, is your question about that, or how to handle your questions being edited?

Comment: @TimmyJim: Were you editing your own posts or others'?

Comment: Others.  I was going for a badge at the time... ☺

Comment: @TimmyJim: The question isn't about my questions/answers being edited. I want to fix the defective posts and asked how often I should perform edits. Of course others can modify these posts as well, but I don't expect it.

Comment: I see what you are asking now also.  I would say that if it was me (especially given I was once asked by mods to stop), I would try to avoid making many edits quickly, especially if they are minor, even to my own posts.  It's not often people find they need to edit a large number of their own posts, so it's kind of a grey area.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every edit to a post bumps it onto the front page. Multiple edits to different posts in quick succession therefore has a tendency to 'flood' the front page, pushing more active content further down the page. There's no real "rule" against it but like Timmy has stated it tends to be frowned upon.

The advice I've given in the past is to do ~4-5 edits at a time and wait a few hours, then do a couple more, and so on. Doing it this way avoids flooding the home page but still allows you to fix up old posts.

On the fixing of alt-text specifically, you may find these queries useful (from a [previous answer](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7474/28182) of mine):

- [My Posts Containing Images](http://data.stackexchange.com/gaming/query/127142/my-posts-containing-images) - All your posts containing images, so you can check them all and make sure the alt text is descriptive.
- [My Posts containing images with default text](http://data.stackexchange.com/gaming/query/323837/my-posts-containing-images-with-default-text) - This will only find your posts with the default "enter image description here" text.