# Am I allowed to ask questions about streaming?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Say for example, I have issues with Quake 3 when trying to stream with Open Broadcast Software (OBS), and I want to ask how to resolve that problem, or that Path of Exile has an option for twitch, but (for instance) it doesn't work.

Am I allowed to ask these kind of questions?

Comment: Related discussion about Fraps and friends: [When is non-game-specific still on-topic?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7608/when-is-non-game-specific-still-on-topic)

Comment: Twitch I'd be pretty lenient on; I was going to say everything about it would be fine, but going much beyond something like "How do I cast to Twitch and save for YouTube simultaneously?" gets iffy

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's on-topic so long as the problem is tied to gaming.

As a rule of thumb, if you can remove every mention of games or gaming from the question and have it still fully describe your problem, then it's *probably* off-topic here and better asked at SuperUser. If removing those mentions from the question fundamentally changes the problem it describes though, this is probably the right place to ask. Your Quake 3 example seems to pass that rule of thumb, and the Path of Exile example definitely does.

A small ([and somewhat debated](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7608/when-is-non-game-specific-still-on-topic)) exception is for software that is designed primarily for gaming use: that's currently considered almost always on-topic here, because problems with software that is primarily designed for and used by gamers for gaming is almost always about (wait for it...) gaming. For stuff like that, [our current consensus](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7608/when-is-non-game-specific-still-on-topic) is that it's generally on-topic without needing to mention a specific game.

Answer (score 8):

Streaming is a huge part of Gaming, so I think that falls under our on-topic scope.