# Update the FAQ tag or create a new tag

Tags: discussion, retag-request, meta

**Closely related:** [What questions should be in our meta FAQ?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5165/what-questions-should-be-in-our-meta-faq)

At least once a week I bump into a meta post about some site policy and I only feel like I should have read that ages ago. As it stands, the [help](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help) pages are very limited, which helps new users to understand the site better, but there is no easy way to get to all the important meta posts, especially the important and **up-to-date** site-policies.

The [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tag works well, and it is even [linked from the help page](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/more-help), but it has not been updated with new questions in a long time. Questions where a new final site policy is reached should also be tagged with [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) ***or*** some new tag, which should also be linked from the help page or, in some cases, both, if a new tag is created.

As it stands, the easiest way to find out about policies is to browse the [site-policies](/questions/tagged/site-policies) using votes to order the list, and that's only slightly easier than making a mistake on the site and having someone comment with a link to related meta post.

So, can we have [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) contain all the important meta posts that everyone should be aware of?

Comment: Huh... I could've sworn we had a tag for that. Maybe it got mentioned, but never implemented.

Comment: @Fluttershy If one exists, I can't (seem to) find it.

Comment: The point is to also have the tag in help so it can be easily found by new users without browsing the meta site for tags.

Answer (score 7):

Please don't create a new tag; the case you're describing is *exactly* the use case for the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tag. "FAQ" is something of a misnomer (which is part of why the official SE FAQ was renamed to "help"), but it IS meant to be used for essential knowledge that new users need to be a successful contributor to this site.

You should add the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tag to any posts you think are essential reading or that you frequently reference in explaining policies to new users.

Comment: Up to the moderators to update the FAQ tag then. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @3ventic You can use the flagging system to notify mods of questions that should have the tag.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I'll do that when I find some. As I stated in the question, it's not very easy to find the important metas at the moment.

Comment: So this post should have a meta-faq tag?