# Is asking about the plot of a game accepted here?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Sometimes we have questions about the story of a game when it's confusing for us to understand one point; and many other reasons.

Can we ask these questions here?

Comment: Related meta posts on lore and "developer intent on mechanics and narrative":  [Should lore questions as an entire category be banned?](/q/7696/4797) | [When is it appropriate to close a lore question as “not addressed directly through in-universe sources”?](/q/7673/4797) | [Is “This question requires developer only knowledge” the same thing as developer intent?](/q/9901/4797) | [Do we close plot-explanation questions if the answer is 'there is no explanation'?](/q/8473/4797)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the [help page](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> Plot and characters in games

is considered on-topic.

That said, there are some things that might make it off-topic.  Such as:

> Speculations on future of the industry, upcoming (but unreleased) games or content, and developer intent on mechanics and narrative

Comment: Related meta posts on lore and "developer intent on mechanics and narrative": [When is it appropriate to close a lore question as “not addressed directly through in-universe sources”?](//meta.arqade.com/q/7673/4797) | [Is “This question requires developer only knowledge” the same thing as developer intent?](//meta.arqade.com/q/9901/4797) | [Do we close plot-explanation questions if the answer is 'there is no explanation'?](//meta.arqade.com/q/8473/4797)